# Need to create a qt QTButton with multiple colors

Tags: qt, qt5

I am looking for how to create a QT button with multiple color in background color.

Button should look like this

[image]

Comment: Show the C++/QML/whatever code you currently have, and how your button currently looks.

Comment: Do you need a QML, QPushButton or QToolButton solution? The simple answer is to use QToolButton with background image.

Comment: I want to fill color to QPushButton not an image

Answer (score 0):

if using a QPushButton then you can play with the stylesheet

for example setting following style to a button

```
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:0.495 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:0.505 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255));
```

will produce this button

[image]